# how do I make a floatSliderGrp take a function as a command?

Tags: python, maya

I am still really new to python and scripting in general and I'm trying to create a UI that will create a floatSliderGrp in maya that, when changed, will call a function that queries their values. 
When I run the script I get the following error:
KeyError: 'moop_slider'
thank you very much for any help

I have the UI working, here is the part of the code that I am having issues with:

```
self.ui_elements['moop_slider'] = cmds.floatSliderGrp(label='moopy',
field=True, minValue = 0, maxValue = 1, value = 5, changeCommand = 
self.what_value())

def what_value(self):
      self.my_moop=
      cmds.floatSliderGrp(self.ui_elements['moop_slider'],q=True,v=True) 
      print self.my_moop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 changeCommand = self.what_value()
```

Is going to fail because it's trying to *call* the function -- but the function needs the value of the dictionary entry to function.  If you remove the parens it should work as written:

```
self.ui_elements['moop_slider'] = cmds.floatSliderGrp(label='moopy', field=True, minValue = 0, maxValue = 1, value = 5, changeCommand = self.what_value)
```

Comment: thank you theodox, that does work.  Im not sure I really understand the difference, again im very new to scripting so forgive the stupid question, but am I not trying to call the function either way?

Comment: You don't want call the function when you assign it to `command =` -- that would assign the _result_ of the function,  rather than telling maya 'call this function when I click'\

Answer (score 0):

It means that `moop_slider` is an invalid key (doesn't exist in your dictionary). As to why it doesn't exist, that I can't help you with.